# How do you properly configure SXA Page List with custom query?

Tags: sxa

Testing with SXA 1.2 on Sitecore 8.2 u1/u2.

I'm trying to query a list of pages marked as featured.

Here is what I have setup:

- *Custom Page* template inherits from *Page*.
- Checkbox field is added with **IsFeatured** field.

[image: Custom Page Item]

- Query defined to return featured pages.

```plaintext
+location:{29E0ED6F-452B-45A0-B799-C51EBD14970A};template:{13de59b4-ad71-4542-9ce0-a0483422e768};custom:isfeatured|true
```

[image: Query]

- The query item does not have a way to build the query, so I used the datasource

[image: Query Builder]
[image: Filter Configured]

Unfortunately, when I test the page no results are returned.

[image: Not working]
[image: Not rendered]

#### Update

Test with a new query that has a `+` for each setting but does not change the behavior.

[image: Still not working]

### Update 2

Oddly, when I move the query to the Data Source field and clear the Source Type I get an error. Not seen this before.

[image: Data Source set]

[image: error]

Comment: Try to set Data Source field in the Page List rendering Control Properties dialogue (for example to root of your website or parent of the items you are looking for.

Comment: I think it also persists in 9.3 - having all sorts of fun with 9.3 queries in components, query item rendering variants and actual query items under settings (SXA) - tell me if I am wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, somewhere along the way, Sitecore (at this time we're on 8.2 U2) lost its capability to have more than a single item provided as a data source.

Unfortunately, Query does not seem to be working in this version of Sitecore for when it returns more than 1 item AND SXA 1.2 breaks content search in data source mechanism altogether.

This will, however, have a workaround in SXA 1.3 where you will be able to use Lucene queries in the "query" item:

[image: SXA Query]

Once created, you will be able to use the query in Page List as follows.

In Rendering Parameters:

[image]

Select the query returning multiple items:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to build the query with **+** signs, like that:

[image]

Comment: I tried changing it to that but the issue persists.

Comment: @MichaelWest were you able to resolve this issue , looks like the same issue persists in SXA 1.8 as well