# Which SXA component supports pulling data from a multilist field

Tags: sxa, fieldtype

Is there an SXA component that supports a rendering variant that can pull data from a multilist field?

In Sitecore SXA 1.4, I want to allow editors to select from a multilist of simple items (text and icon, not a page). I have tried using a Page List with the datasource set to an item that contains a multilist. I changed the Source Type of the rendering to "Items of the same template" but it displayed and empty in the page.

I've been recommended to use item queries, but I don't understand where to apply that. Any help much appreciated.

My alternative is to extend an existing SXA component, but my request isn't particularly complicated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because crossposting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49663412/which-sxa-component-supports-pulling-data-from-a-multilist-field

Comment: Apologies for the double post. Can we keep this one open and close the SO one?

Comment: Sure. Just flag this post for moderator attention when the SO post has been deleted, and I'll be happy to reopen :-)

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a blog on that here: https://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2017/04/sitecore-sxa-pagelist-item-query.html

Steps to take:

1. Create an `item query` that will fetch your data (the items with text and icon)
2. Create a `variant` for the `PageList` component to display the fields you want displayed
3. Create your PageList component: select the variant you just created and in the `Source Type` you should find the item query you defined in step 1.

The item query part is explained in detail [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/4706/237) as well.